# Decimal type format with comma but retain precision

Tags: c#

I have a decimal that can can contain the following values and expected results

- 1000.00001 > 1,000.00001
- .1 > 00.10
- 5 > 5.00
- 900 > 900.00
- .00000001 > 00000001

Basically I would like at least 2 decimal points if there is 2 or less and all if there is more (with 0's trimmed from the end)
And if there is more than 3 digits I would like to add a comma, if there is less than 3 then nothing unless that value is less than 1 then add 00 infront

I have tried

```
 private string FormatNumber(decimal number)
 {
      return number.ToString("#,###.########");
 }
```

Comment: `"#,###.00######"`. Zero for "fill in with zero if there's less actual precision".

Comment: that did it, if u can put that as an answer, i will mark it for you, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string should be `"#,###.00######"`.

[Zero for "fill in with zero if there's less actual precision"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the-0-custom-specifier). Once you've started specifying what goes to the right of the decimal point, I'm afraid there's no way to specify "all the digits" other than just adding a great pile of `#`.

Comment: Is there a way to handle the `.1 > 00.10` and
`5 > 5.00` situations as well? I tried `#,#00.00######` but that was giving `05.00`

Comment: I'm afraid that may be more than the custom formatting can do. If it's absolutely needed, you'd have to start writing some custom code to make that happen. Or settle for `#,##0.00#####`